# Android studio Error:Could not open cache fileSnapshots.bin java.io.IOException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build my project but I keep getting this error:

[image]

I tried to delete the file manually but it keeps reappearing.